# Mockito-Kotlin in Android Studio. How to Inject property when my class has constructor?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, mockito

I have class with constructor and private property.

I try to pass each property

1. 'a_property' by injectMocks
2. 'b_property' by constructor parameter

but it doesn't work.

How can I test this class?

```
class ClassForTest constructor( private var b_property : AnotherClass){

    private var a_property: SomeClass = SomeClass()

    fun aMethod() {
        a_property.someMethod()
    }

}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class A_classTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var a_property: SomeClass

    @Mock
    lateinit var b_property: AnotherClass

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var classForTest: ClassForTest

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        classForTest = ClassForTest(b_property)
    }

    @Test
    fun registerFilter() {

        classForTest.aMethod()

        verify(a_property).someMethod()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you mocking the class that is being tested?  That makes no sense to me at all.  Mocks are for dependencies, not the class under scrutiny.

Comment: I agree with duffymo, why do you have @InjectMocks over `classForTest`

Comment: i'm newbie in unit test and mockito.

Comment: i just want to know a_property.someMethod() invoked.

Comment: And I thought @InjectMocks needed for getting Mocked object, so i can verify 'someMethod()' invoking